# How to check login session status using ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code which checks for session status.Everything is right about this code but it doesn't redirect me to the login.php page,Please help me.Where have i gone wrong?

```
function checkLoginStatus() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkstatus.php",
            success: function(res){
                if(res == "0") {
                     window.location = "login.php"; 
                }
            }
    });
}

// checkstatus.php

 <?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION["email"]))
  {
     echo "1";
  } else {
     echo "0";
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Did you console check what value does `res` object has?

Comment: Anyhow, check for `res.data`, if success, i.e `if(res.data == "0") {window.location.href = "login.php"; }`

Comment: use `res.indexOf("0") !== -1` in javascript code. Becasuse many times response has spaces in it.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
window.location.href = "/login.php";
```

As far as your login-page is reachable over http://yourdomain.com/login.php